# Xcopy or Robocopy Only files that have a certain date on the destination file

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

I'm trying to restore files that have been encrypted by cryptowall.  I have the files copied onto an external drive that I'd like to copy over the destination files on the data drive.

I know exactly what dates the encryption happened. So I'd like to run a script to copy over only the files where the destination date is XX:XX:XX.  It appears the /d option only looks at the source file and not the date of the destination file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to copy the whole external drive over the data drive, overwriting everything bad and good, but I assume you have reasons that won't work for you?  If so ...

I always prefer a 2 pane file manager for these types of operations, Total Commander being my favorite, but others will work too.  TC has a folder comparison tool that compares both folders and marks those files which are newer or only existing on one side.  You would then delete the marked/encrypted files, then re-compare folders and copy the marked files on the external drive to the data drive.